# Get the new value or index with SelectionChangeCommitted Event of DataGridView Combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, selectedindexchanged, datagridviewcombobox

im using SelectionChangeCommitted to catch the event when a combobox selected index changed, but I can not get it's new value or index.

```
private void ruleList_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += ruleListColumnComboSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ruleListColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = ruleList.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(); // just return the old value before the change
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using the `CommitEdit` keyword ([`CommitEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit%28VS.80%29.aspx), there is also an example on the MSDN page).  Add this to your `DataGridView`:

```
// This event handler manually raises the CellValueChanged event
// by calling the CommitEdit method.
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Then you could just listen for the [`CellValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) and avoid having to try and register for the ComboBoxValueChanged event on the underlying editing control.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the new Value using:

```
ComboBox comboBox = sender.Control as ComboBox;
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are reacting on the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event from a combobox, but trying to get the value via a grid. Is that correct?

- How is the commitment in the ruleList done?
- Did the commitment already happen at that point in time?

My feeling here is that via this `SelectionChangeCommitted` event you can access the value from the combobox directly, but not yet via the grid since it is not commited yet.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on [Killercam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626442/killercam)'s method, you can check for the currentcell being a datagridviewcomboboxcell and do (in VB which you can easily convert to C#)

```
If TypeOf CType(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell Is DataGridViewComboBoxCell Then
    CType(sender, DataGridView).CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    CType(sender, DataGridView).EndEdit()
End If
```

I also added the **EndEdit()** method for completeness.