# ComboBox got new SelectedValue on SelectionChangeCommitted but doesn't got new SelectedText

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have this code

```
private void FrmNovedadMedidas_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox c = (ComboBox)sender;
            CargarMedidasPorIdTipoMedida(Convert.ToInt16(c.SelectedValue));
            this.txtBoxNombreTipoMedida.Text = c.SelectedText;
        }
```

in `c.SelectedValue` got the new value of the selection (the one that the user has selected in the Combo).
But in `c.SelectedText` I got the old value of the ComboBox (I mean, the one that was before the user change the selection).

Is there any property that can give me the new Selected Text?
I want to avoid to search in the DataSet binded to the ComboBox everytime.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090847/get-the-new-value-or-index-with-selectionchangecommitted-event-of-datagridview-c) but doesn't work, I don't have `CommitEdit()` in ComboBox

edit:

`c.Text` also gives me the old one

Comment: I seem to remember this situation having to do with the DropDownStyle of the ComboBox. Can you please try different styles and see if the Text property is set to the new value inside SelectionChangeCommited ?

Comment: Using DropDownList solve this, and also solve another problem that I was checking. Thanks so much !! Please post it as an answer So I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to remember this situation having to do with the `DropDownStyle` of the ComboBox.

Can you please try different styles and see if the Text property is set to the new value inside `SelectionChangeCommited` ?

As per your comment, it seems using `DropDownList` style solves the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I found something.

```
c.GetItemText(c.SelectedItem)
```

Is there a directly properties, post it please.
Thanks for readme anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the ComboBox versus the `SelectionChangeCommited` event. Then use `c.Text` to get the value the user just selected.

Comment: The problem is that in that case fire even the programatically selection changes, and I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

`c.SelectedValue()` returns `null` for me.

`c.GetItemText(c.SelectedItem)` works for me though. Changing the dropdownstyle wasn't an option.